# Create dataframe with header using header and data file

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have two files data.csv and headers.csv. I want to create dataframe in Spark/Scala with headers.

```
var data = spark.sqlContext.read.format(
  "com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true"
).option("inferSchema", "true").load(data_path)
```

Can you help me customizing above lines to do this?

Comment: you read the headers.csv using header option and create schema from that and use the schema to the data.csv.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can read the `headers.csv` by using the above method and use the `schema` of headers `dataframe` to read the `data.csv` as below

```
val headersDF = sqlContext
  .read
  .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
  .option("header", "true")
  .load("path to headers.csv")

val schema = headersDF.schema

val dataDF = sqlContext
  .read
  .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
  .schema(schema)
  .load("path to data.csv")
```

I hope the answer is helpful

Comment: great to hear that :) you can accept the answer too :)

Comment: @Ravikrn providing answers takes valuable time for the respondents; since the proposed solution worked, please show some courtesy and accept the answer.